# JavaScript loop performance - Why is to decrement the iterator toward 0 faster than incrementing

Tags: javascript, performance, loops

In his book [Even Faster Web Sites](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/23/even-faster-web-sites/) Steve Sounders writes that a simple way to improve the performance of a loop is to decrement the iterator toward 0 rather than incrementing toward the total length (*actually the chapter was written by Nicholas C. Zakas*). This change can result in savings of up to 50% off the original execution time, depending on the complexity of each iteration. For example:

```
var values = [1,2,3,4,5];
var length = values.length;

for (var i=length; i--;) {
   process(values[i]);
}
```

This is nearly identical for the `for` loop, the `do-while` loop, and the `while` loop.

I'm wondering, what's the reason for this? **Why is to decrement the iterator so much faster?** (I'm interested in the technical background of this and not in benchmarks proving this claim.)

---

EDIT: At first sight the loop syntax used here looks wrong. There is no `length-1` or `i>=0`, so let's clarify (I was confused too).

Here is the general for loop syntax:

```
for ([initial-expression]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

- *initial-expression* - `var i=length`

  This variable declaration is evaluated first.
- *condition* - `i--`

  This expression is evaluated before each loop iteration. It will decrement the variable before the first pass through the loop. If this expression evaluates to `false` the loop ends. In JavaScript is `0 == false` so if `i` finally equals `0` it is interpreted as `false` and the loop ends.
- *final-expression*

  This expression is evaluated at the end of each loop iteration (before the next evaluation of *condition*). It's not needed here and is empty. All three expressions are optional in a for loop.

The for loop syntax is not part of the question, but because it's a little bit uncommon I think it's interesting to clarify it. And maybe one reason it's faster is, because it uses less expressions (the `0 == false` "trick").

Comment: aren't you missing a termination condition?

Comment: The termination condition is `i--`.  It'll be 0 (false) when i is 0 before decrementing.  Since the condition has the side effect of decrementing the variable itself, there's no need for the third (change/increment/whatever) expression in the statement.

Comment: @Gumbo - Why do I have to start with length-1? You can replace process with alert to check.
@Dave - The terminal condition evaluates to true if the i equals 0

Comment: @Soundlink: Actually, it evaluates to *false* if i is 0.  It evaluates true the rest of the time.

Comment: @Gumbo: The first time through the loop checks the condition -- read: it evaluates `i--`.

Comment: @Gumbo, @Dave: sorry I added +1 to both your comments, but they are WRONG! You MUST start loop with i = length because (i--) is evaluated before the 1st loop. And no termination condition is necessary here.

Comment: wondering if any answers helped..!

Comment: So why are decrement operations in Chrome so much slower with access to `.length` outside the while loop? http://jsperf.com/preincrement-vs-postincrement-vs-predecrement-vs-postde/5

Comment: exact duplicate of [Are loops really faster in reverse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1340589/1048572)

Answer (score 68):

I'm not sure about Javascript, and under modern compilers it probably doesn't matter, but in the "olden days" this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
  .. body..
}
```

would generate

```
move register, 0
L1:
compare register, n
jump-if-greater-or-equal L2
-- body ..
increment register
jump L1
L2:
```

while the backward-counting code

```
for (i = n; --i>=0;){
  .. body ..
}
```

would generate

```
move register, n
L1:
decrement-and-jump-if-negative register, L2
.. body ..
jump L1
L2:
```

so inside the loop it's only doing two extra instructions instead of four.

Comment: Worth noting that "in the olden days" javascript would never have been converted into machine code, so it's a little bit of a moot point.

Comment: @skeggse JavaScript still has an interpreter i.e. the browser, that has to decide how to execute the code. While it doesn't exactly get "compiled", it has to be sent to the processor some how. What should have been said was _interpreter_ instead of _compiler_, but to say it doesn't get turned into machine code cannot be completely accurate. Although that's to the browser's discretion. [Mozilla uses Spider Monkey for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey)

Comment: @haelmic pretty sure we're saying the same thing. Original implementations of javascript consisted of an interpreter, whereas modern versions such as Spider Monkey and V8 selectively JIT-compile code.

Answer (score 29):

I believe the reason is because you're comparing the loop end point against 0, which is faster then comparing again  `< length` (or another JS variable).

It is because the ordinal operators `<, <=, >, >=` are polymorphic, so these operators require type checks on both left and right sides of the operator to determine what comparison behaviour should be used.

There's some very good benchmarks available here:

**[What's the Fastest Way to Code a Loop in JavaScript](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205235948/https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a)**

Comment: Very interesting link, it's a pity he didn't add the test with for loop using prefix ++i operator, according to http://www.prototypejs.org/api/array should be faster rather than using postfix i++ increment operator.

Comment: Any difference between pre- (++i) and post- (i++) is dependent on the browser's implementation of Javascript (or is vanishingly small). The logic difference is _far_ more important (Douglas Crockford has pointed out it's awfully easy to get the logic wrong with this construct.) The pre- (++i) version increments/decrements _before_ the rest of the statement, while the post- (i++) version increments/decrements _after_. i-- works as the order is (1]exit if 0, 2]decrement, 3]perform loop); --i would fail as the order (1]decrement, 2]exit if 0, 3]perform loop) would never handle the 0th element.

Answer (score 15):

It is easy to say that an iteration can have less instructions. Let’s just compare these two:

```
for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
}

for (var i=length; i--;) {
}
```

When you count each variable access and each operator as one instruction, the former `for` loop uses 5 instructions (read `i`, read `length`, evaluate `i<length`, test `(i<length) == true`, increment `i`) while the latter uses just 3 instructions (read `i`, test `i == true`, decrement `i`). That is a ratio of 5:3.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to set `i = length`, since the `for` loop does the conditional test for the first iteration as well?

Comment: You missed "Read i" in counting number of instructions in latter for loop which makes the ratio 5:3.

Answer (score 6):

What about using a reverse while loop then:

```
var values = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
var i = values.length; 

/* i is 1st evaluated and then decremented, when i is 1 the code inside the loop 
   is then processed for the last time with i = 0. */
while(i--)
{
   //1st time in here i is (length - 1) so it's ok!
   process(values[i]);
}
```

IMO this one at least is a more readble code than `for(i=length; i--;)`

Comment: The question is not to find a more readable syntax, but to find an explanation why to decrement the iterator is faster.

Comment: You have the best answer,    while(i--)  is the fastest as per :  https://jsperf.com/while-vs-for

Answer (score 4):

### `for` increment vs. decrement in 2017

In modern JS engines incrementing in `for` loops is generally faster than decrementing (based on personal Benchmark.js tests), also more conventional:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { ... }
```

It depends on the platform and array length if `length = array.length` has any considerable positive effect, but usually it doesn't:

```
for (let i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) { ... }
```

Recent V8 versions (Chrome, Node) have optimizations for `array.length`, so `length = array.length` can be efficiently omitted there in any case.

Comment: increment is still faster than decrement in 2019 https://jsperf.com/ppi-vs-ipp-forloop/9

Answer (score 3):

There is an even more "performant" version of this.
Since each argument is optional in for loops you can skip even the first one.

```
var array = [...];
var i = array.length;

for(;i--;) {
    do_teh_magic();
}
```

With this you skip even the check on the `[initial-expression]`. So you end up with just one operation left.

Comment: Hey Andreas, FYI this is totally equivalent to the for loop explained by @Gumbo. You just took the initialization part outside for loop which is anyways taking same time. Moreover, now you should better convert for to while.

Comment: also if some operation modifies the counter and you 'skip' over the zero, you got an infinite loop. granted, an unlikely scenario, but it's still a good idea to do something like `for(;i-->=0;)`

Comment: Just use while, which is even faster

Answer (score 3):

I've been exploring loop speed as well, and was interested to find this tidbit about decrementing being faster than incrementing. However, I have yet to find a test that demonstrates this. There are lots of loop benchmarks on jsperf. Here is one that tests decrementing:

http://jsperf.com/array-length-vs-cached/6

Caching your array length, however (also recommended Steve Souders' book) does seem to be a winning optimization.

Comment: Actually, it does seem to be faster in Safari -- so frustrating that every browser is different!

Answer (score 3):

in modern JS engines, the difference between forward and reverse loops is almost non-existent anymore. But the performance difference comes down to 2 things:

a) extra lookup every of length property every cycle

```js
//example:
    for(var i = 0; src.length > i; i++)
//vs
    for(var i = 0, len = src.length; len > i; i++)
```

this is the biggest performance gain of a reverse loop, and can obviously be applied to forward loops.

b) extra variable assignment.

the smaller gain of a reverse loop is that it only requires one variable assignment instead of 2

```js
//example:
    var i = src.length; while(i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've conducted a benchmark on C# and C++ (similar syntax). There, actually, the performance differs essentially in `for` loops, as compared to `do while` or `while`. In C++, performance is greater when incrementing. It may also depend on the compiler.

In Javascript, I reckon, it all depends on the browser (Javascript engine), but this behavior is to be expected. Javascript is optimized for working with DOM. So imagine you loop through a collection of DOM elements you get at each iteration, and you increment a counter, when you have to remove them. You remove the `0` element, then `1` element, but then you skip the one that takes `0`'s place. When looping backwards that problem disappears. I know that the example given isn't just the right one, but I did encounter situations where I had to delete items from an ever-changing object collection.

Because backward looping is more often inevitable than forward looping, I am guessing that the JS engine is optimized just for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's faster but one reason i see is that when you iterate over an array of large elements using increment you tend to write:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 ...
}
```

You are essentially accessing the length property of the array N (number of elements) times.
Whereas when you decrement, you access it only once. That could be a reason.

But you can also write incrementing loop as follows:

```
for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: It's true, that accessing the length property N times is bad, but I don't think that's the reason, because in his book he has already considered that for the incrementing loop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you timed it yourself? Mr. Sounders might be wrong with regards to modern interpreters. This is precisely the sort of optimization in which a good compiler writer can make a big difference.

Comment: No, I have not timed it myself. It would be interesting to know if the current JavaScript engines behave different.

Comment: @Soundlink: You presumably have at least one web browser (as evidenced by the fact that you're posting on a web site).  Try it out.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** faster (at least in modern browsers):

```js
// Double loops to check the initialization performance too
const repeats = 1e3;
const length = 1e5;

console.time('Forward');
for (let j = 0; j < repeats; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {}
}
console.timeEnd('Forward'); // 58ms

console.time('Backward');
for (let j = repeats; j--;) {
  for (let i = length; i--;) {}
}
console.timeEnd('Backward'); // 64ms
```

The difference is even bigger in case of an array iteration:

```js
const repeats = 1e3;
const array = [...Array(1e5)];

console.time('Forward');
for (let j = 0; j < repeats; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {}
}
console.timeEnd('Forward'); // 34ms

console.time('Backward');
for (let j = 0; j < repeats; j++) {
  for (let i = array.length; i--;) {}
}
console.timeEnd('Backward'); // 64ms
```