# Why is iterating through an array backwards faster than forwards

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

Given this code:

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    arr.push(1);
```

**Forwards**

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {}
```

**Backwards**

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {}
```

**Hard-coded Forward**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {}
```

Why is backwards so much faster?

Here is the test:
http://jsperf.com/array-iteration-direction

Comment: Note that your backwards case should start at `arr.length-1` and have `i >= 0` rather than `i > 0`.

Comment: The title is misleading. It is no longer the case that directly using arr.length *is* slower in advanced browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript loop performance - Why is to decrement the iterator toward 0 faster than incrementing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3520688/1048572)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Because your forwards-condition has to receive the `length` property of your array each time, whilst the other condition only has to check for "greater then zero", a very fast task.

When your array length doesn't change during the loop, and you really look at ns-perfomance, you can use

```
for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++)
```

BTW: Instead of `for (var i = arr.length; i > 0; --i)` you might use `for (var i = arr.length; i-- > 0; )` which really runs through your array from n-1 to 0, not from n to 1.

Comment: Yep, this is how I do it for optimized functions. Just note that if the array is mutable (and it usually isn't), this may skip a resource or two. For example, this won't work if you're looping through elements that the loop itself is adding or deleting.

Comment: you can even do `for(... ; i-- ;)`

Comment: so basically it means that if I don't change the array and I keep array.length in a variable, then backwards speed = forward speed?

Example:
var length = array.length;
for(var i = 0 ; i<length ; i++);

Comment: afaik, `i<l` is a different computation than `i>0`, but yes they're rather equal (faster than uncached length): http://jsperf.com/array-iteration-direction/3 - yet some engines do recognize and optimize some of these cases

Comment: The condition of a loop is evaluated on each iteration. Think of it like `var i = 0; var a = i < 10; while(a) { i++; a = i < 10; }`.

Comment: @bryc: So what? Of course it needs to be. Did I say something else?

Comment: Isnt this loop `for (var i = arr.length; i-- > 0; )` going to miss 0 index as 1-- !>0? maybe this one needs to be `for (var i = arr.length; i-- >= 0; )`

Comment: @MaxYari: No. The `i` in the loop body (after being decremented) is always one smaller than the `i` seen in the condition (before being decremented). What you would need is `for (var i=arr.length-1; i>=0; --i)`

Comment: tested, yes 0 is here, i honestly did not understand yet why, isnt it in the first place decrements `i`, then compares to 0, then decides to run iteration or not. Like this, it seems that 1 must be decremented to 0, therefore not starting iteration as it's not > 0

Comment: @MaxYari: Read on [prefix/postfix decrement operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6867876/1048572) then

Comment: Oh snap!! you opened my eyes, what a shame, thank you)

Comment: Fast forward to 2018. it looks like the modern versions of browsers don't make loop slower even when accessing arr.length in each iteration (your forwards case)

Answer (score 9):

Because in the first form you are accessing the property `length` of the array `arr` once for every iteration, whereas in the second you only do it once.

Comment: @samccone - what result are you seeing (which test in which browser)?  I'm seeing that caching the length is always at least as fast and usually faster.

Comment: alright you are correct... it looks like it is really a mixed bag of results tho but caching does help it... thanks XD

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have them at same pace, you can do that for forward iteration;

```
for(var i=0, c=arr.length; i<c; i++){
}
```

So, your script won't need to take length of array on everystep.

Comment: Ahhh... interesting your method now takes the crown for fastest iteration http://jsperf.com/array-iteration-direction

Answer (score 5):

I am not entirely sure about this, but here is my guess:

For the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {;
}
```

During runtime, there is an arr.length calculation after each loop pass. This may be a trivial operation when it stands alone, but may have an impact when it comes to multiple/huge arrays. Can you try the following:

```
 var numItems = arr.length;
    for(var i=0; i< numItems; ++i)
    {
    }
```

In the above code, we compute the array length just once, and operate with that computed number, rather than performing the length computation over and over again.

Again, just putting my thoughts out here. Interesting observation indeed!

Answer (score 3):

`i > 0` is faster than `i < arr.length` and is occurring on each iteration of the loop.

You can mitigate the difference with this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {;
}
```

This is still not as fast as the backwards item, but faster than your forward option.

Comment: look at the hard coded test http://jsperf.com/array-iteration-direction ... using your logic it should be faster no?

Answer (score 2):

And these are equally good:

```
var arr= [], L= 10000;
while(L>-1) arr[L]= L--;
```

OR

```
var arr= [], i= 0;
while(i<10001) arr[i]=i++;
```

Comment: It should be `while(--L>=0) arr[L] = L;`

Answer (score 2):

do it like below, it will perform in same way. because `arr.length` takes time in each iteration in forward.

```
int len = arr.length;
```

**forward**

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
}
```

**backward**

```
for (var i = len; i > 0; --i) {
}
```

Comment: The backward case isn't right. What I do is `for(i=len; --i>=0;){`

Comment: `for (let i = arr.length; i-- > 0;) {`