# Input 10 Strings, print the largest One

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new in java and have a problem writing my code. The problm is, im taking 10 strings from user and wants to print the largest one out all 10 strings.The Input Section works well, But there is an IDE error: "of bad operands for binary '>' operator" while using if condition . The code is below..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Largest_String {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


         Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter The 10 Strings: ");
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){


            System.out.print(i+") ");
            String str=input.nextLine();

            String array[]=new String[10];



            for(int j=10; j>0; j++){

            if(array[i]>array[j]){

            System.out.println("The Largest String if"+ array[i]);
            }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean 'largest string'? longest? or Ascii sum largest? or what?

Comment: Also, your indexing with `i` (and `j`) will give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds after you correct `j++` to `j--` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a slightly different way of doing it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Largest_String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter The 10 Strings: ");

         String longest = "";

         for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter String "+(i+1)+": ");
            String str=input.nextLine();
            if( str.length() > longest.length() )
            {
               longest = str;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Largest String is "+ longest);
     }
 }
```

comment: get used to doing your loops 0-based

Comment: Its not ideal to paste code on homework-tagged question, you can answer with ideas.

Comment: pardon me, i shall refrain in the future

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir was near about to done it, actually im new and don't know the syntax of java properly. But you people helped me out and i have done it.

Comment: you should accept an answer as the correct one. if none of them are correct, post the correct one yourself and accept that one. good luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

```
array[i].length()>array[j].length()
```

you need to compare string length and not the string itself.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays that are subject to the '>' operator are of type String, so this is not a valid operator.

If you want to confirm the longest string (number of characters) then you should perform the comparison on the length of the strings as follows:

```
if(array[i].length() >array[j].length() ){
```

Comment: Thankx a lot guys, i have done it. I have learned new and useful things from you all. Thank you all once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lenght()](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/StringLength1.shtml) of individual string in array.  This is the method that returns the length of given string in integer type. You are using the `>` operator for strings, use it for integers i.e., length of each string.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `array[i].length>array[j].length` to compare the lengths of the strings.
2. `for(int j=10; j>0; j++)`: this will give you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when j is greater than elements in `array`
3. The idea:

   1. read in user input
   2. check if this input is longer than the previously entered value (use 0 as initial value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a good long look at your loop nesting. It looks something
like this:

```
for (/* i */) {
    String array[] = new String[10];
    for (/* j */) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The end result of this nesting is that you're creating *ten* arrays, each
with ten elements. Move the array *outside* the outer `for` loop, and make
sure you know why.

Next thing, focus on the loop indexes and how you use them to index into
the arrays:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    String array[] = new String[10];
    for (int j = 10; j > 0; j++) {
        if (array[i] > array[j]) {
        }
    }
}
```

An array declared as `new String[10]` has valid indices: `0`, `1`, `2`,
`3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`. You're accessing `array[10]` in this
loop, which will blow up with an out-of-range exception. (You are also
*incrementing* with `j++`, but intended to start at the end of the array
and count down. Oops.)

When iterating over an array, it is best to stick to this formula:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

If you want to count down, you can, but it is more tricky:

```
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

(Again, n-1 to 0, inclusive.) [This
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689573/why-is-iterating-through-an-array-backwards-faster-then-forwards)
shows two additional forms that also work for iterating backwards:

```
for (int i = array.length; --i >= 0; )
for (int i = array.length; i-- > 0; )
```

Though I dislike `for` loops that combine the test and iterative step in
one go, I can definitely respect that both these get the job done
correctly and are likely to be idiomatic.

Iterating backwards is rare.

Comment: Great Sir, for your kind reply. I am much pleased of getting a useful knowledge from your golden words. Thanks a lot.