# Loop optimization changing direction

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have read about loop optimization (N.Zakas, Javascript Optimization). There, it was written that using `inverse loop` for `arrays` is more optimized than direct loop. It seems completely logical:

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){...}
```

- checks condition
- increases variable `i`

```
for(i = length;i--;)
```

- checks condition + increases variable `i` (in one expression)
But, I've got unexpected result for Chrome.

```
var len = 100000000,
arr = new Array(len),
i = len - 1,
start = new Date(), 
end;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    arr[i] = 1;
}

end = new Date();

console.log(end - start);
```

> Direct loop return result near 4500ms, but inversed loop... 9500ms!

Why?

Comment: "is more optimized then direct loop." --- it makes very little sense.

Comment: N. Zakas was talking about unrolling loops and a technique called Duffs Device - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device. Use a `while` loop, not `for`.

Comment: ok, let say better in scope of performance

Comment: "let say better in scope of performance" --- nope, it's not.

Comment: You misread Zakas. Based on http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas, his sample code uses a do while loop, NOT a for loop, in the more efficient version.

Comment: consider also that the cost of array access is going to dwarf the cost of a simple integer comparison.

Comment: sorry, is this statement (about backwards loop) wrong?

Comment: "sorry, is this statement (about backwards loop) wrong?" --- it does not contain all the truth: iterating is not what actually is slow and what should be optimised, but the real work that you do in the loop body. In other words - it's like stating that red cars are faster than blue cars.

Comment: zerkms, thanks I understand but could you explain me why case with for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) faster then for(i = length;i--;)?

Comment: Different code runs with different pace. Something sometimes is "slower" than something else. But there is nothing in the standard that guarantees that status quo keeps indefinitely: one engine can run it one way, the other - the other way.

Answer (score 1):

just because there's less code in `for(i = length;i--;)` doesn't mean less things are getting done; the `i` still needs to be incremented (or in this case, decremented), and a check still needs to take place (where before it was `i < length`, it's now `i != 0`).

I might expect the discrepancy in time to be due to the fact that `for(i = 0; i < length; i++)` is an incredibly common construct, and is thus very common to optimize (so modern compilers/interpreters have resources invested in explicitly optimizing those). But I'll admit this is speculation.

One case where iterating backwards *would* probably show a great increase in speed is when you're popping off the contents of an array:

`for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr.splice(i,1);` might be removing the first element from the array, and shifting all the other elements backwards to fill its spot under the hood.

whereas:

`for(i = arr.length; i--; ) arr.splice(i,1);` might need only decrement the length of the array under the hood (much cheaper!).

I'm not sure if this is the optimization you were going for, but the takaway *isn't* "backwards iteration is faster!" in the general sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [iterating an array backwards can be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8689573/1048572). But that's not what you are doing here. You are *constructing* an array in reverse, and that's quite weird (read: less likely optimised).

If you start assigning the highest indices first, I guess the array starts as a sparse array, which is much less efficient than a contiguous array. Either the assignment itself will be slower for that, or the conversion to a normal array once the engine realises what you are doing.
In contrast, if you start at `0`, the engine can grow the array as necessary, and will use the efficient memory representation from the very beginning. Btw, I'd expect [`arr.fill(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to be even faster.