# How to reverse the order in a FOR loop

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

I've a simple FOR statement like this:

```
var num = 10,
    reverse = false;

for(i=0;i<num;i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

when **reverse** is false I want it to return something like [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

but, when **reverse** is true, it should return [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

Which is the most efficient way to get this result, without checking every time if **reverse** is true or false inside the loop?

I don't want to do this:

```
var num = 10,
    reverse = false;

for(i=0;i<num;i++){
    if(reverse) console.log(num-i)
    else console.log(i)
}
```

I would like to check **reverse** only one time outside the loop.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Because if it's create an array, or loop on an array, there is always the javascript function reverse http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp which you can call

Comment: w3schools is not so good.  Check out [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var num = 10,
reverse = false;

if(!reverse) for( var i=0;i<num;i++) log(i);
else         while(num-- )      log(num);

   // to avoid duplication if the code gets long
function log( num ) { console.log( num ); }
```

---

**EDIT:**

As noted in the comments below, if `i` is not declared elsewhere and you do not intend for it to be global, then declare it with the other variables you declared.

And if you don't want to modify the value of `num`, then assign it to `i` first.

```
var num = 10,
reverse = false,
i;

if(!reverse) for(var i=0;i<num;i++) log(i);   // Count up
else         {var i=num; while(i--) log(i);}  // Count down

function log( num ) { console.log( num ); }
```

Comment: Nice.  I was going to suggest `for(i = num; i--;) log(i);`, but [the consensus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse) seems to be that your method is fastest.

Comment: To the op: be aware that `num` will be modified when printed in reverse, so be sure to make a copy of the original value if you plan to use that value in the future.

Comment: @Daniel - Very true. If that's a concern, here's quick replacement for the `else` statement: `else{i=num;while(i--)log(i)};`

Comment: don't forget to declare `var i` somewhere

Comment: @cobbal - The OP didn't declare it in the question, so I assume it is declared elsewhere, or is intended to be global. If not, then yes, it could be added to the OP's other declarations. `var num = 10, reverse = false, i;`

Answer (score 7):

Try use 2 loops:

```
if (reverse) {
    for(i=num-1;i>=0;i--){
        console.log(i)
    }
}
else {
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to post pretty much the same thing as this. This seems to me the most natural and readable solution, and is also efficient, the reverse flag is tested only once and not every time through the loop.

Answer (score 6):

```
var num = 10,
    reverse = false;

for (var i = 0, n = reverse?num-1:0, d = reverse?-1:1; i < num; i++, n+=d) {
    console.log(n);
}
```

This is equivalent to the following, which is more readable, but less compact:

```
var num = 10,
    reverse = false;

var start = reverse ? num-1 : 0,
    end   = reverse ? -1 : num,
    step  = reverse ? -1 : 1;
for (var i = start; i != end; i += step) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

**Edit:**
Actually, these two solutions are not identical, because the first one has an additional increment operation. Still, it is negligible from performance point of view. If you really want to get a compact solution that has the best performance, you can do the following (not for the faint of heart):

```
var num = 10,
    reverse = false;

for (var r=reverse, i=r?num-1:0, n=r?-1:num, d=r?-1:1; i!=n; i+=d) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

This has the advantage of having a single control structure, a single test in each loop, and a single iterator addition. It is not as fast as having an iterator increment/decrement, but only marginally so.

Comment: lol.  You wrote yours as I was writing mine (the page refreshed when new answers were posted).  :P  I abuse ternary statements.  Glad to see someone who writes like me.

Comment: No abuse of ternaries there... I consider it abuse only if you don't use the return value of the ternary expression like

condition ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse(); --- Completely outside the point, though...

Comment: I like your solution, but I found the patrick's one more clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
var start; var end; var inc;
if (reverse) {
    start = num-1; end = 0; inc = -1;
}
else {
    start = 0; end = num-1; inc = 1;
}
for(i=start;i!=end;i+=inc){
    console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: The `i<=end` will give issues here, since the check needs to be `i>=0` in reverse.

Comment: in the first clause it should be `end=-1`, and in the second clause `end=num`.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the need for this the other day. Here's how I did it:

```
var num = 10,
    i = 0,
    direction = 1, 
    reverse = false;

if(reverse)
    i = num + (direction = num = -1);

for(; i !== num; i += direction) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

No need for separate loops, and no need to do math to calculate the proper `i` in the loop.

So if `reverse` is `true`...

- `i` (which represents our first item) becomes `num - 1`, so we're now starting on what would have been the last item
- `num` (which represents out of bounds) becomes `-1`, so we're now stopping on what would have been the first item
- `direction` is `-1`, which means it will decrement when we do `i += direction`

So by swapping our starting point with our ending point and changing the alteration of `i` from `1` to `-1`, we'll be going up or down based on those modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I think this meets your requirements:

```
var num = 10;
var reverse = false;
var diff = 0;

if (reverse) {
    diff = num - 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    console.log(Math.abs(diff - i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've always done reverse loops:

```
for (i = num; --i >= 0; ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

And what's your problem with:

```
   if (reverse)
   {
     for(i=num-1; i>=0;i--){ 
          console.log(i);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      for(i=0;i<num;i++){ 
         console.log(i) 
      } 
   }
```

}

Comment: Perhaps in production code there will be more going on inside the loop than a simple `console.log`?

Comment: @meagar: If so, push everything inside the loop into a function.

Answer (score 0):

Roy's is similar to mine, but here's what I was thinking.  I'll give you what I wrote in C# and how I think it translates to Javascript.

**C#**

```
    int num = 10;
    bool reverse = true;

    for (int i = reverse ? num : 0; (reverse ? 0 : i) < (reverse ? i : num); i += reverse ? -1 : 1)
    {
        Console.Write((reverse ? i - 1 : i).ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

**Javascript**

```
        var num = 10,
        reverse = true;

    for (int i = reverse ? num : 0; (reverse ? 0 : i) < (reverse ? i : num); i += reverse ? -1 : 1)
    {
        console.log(reverse ? i - 1 : i);
    }
```

**And here's another way**

**Javascript**

```
    var num = 10,
        reverse = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
      console.log((reverse ? abs(-num + (i + 1)) : i));

    }
```

Comment: All of these still test the reverse flag on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: lol. My bad, I didn't see that part in the question. Thanks for letting me know. However, to the OP, if you're worried about performance, I wouldn't. I'll think of something else though, if I can.

Comment: I think the OP wasn't aware of ternary statements, thinking they'd have to have an if/else in their loop.  I'm still thinking about another way though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work:

```
  var num = 10;
  var z = 1;
  var k = -10;
  if (reverse ){
    k = -1;
    z = -1;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log(num+i*z+k);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely in a language like Javascript there must be a way to define a local function and use that in the loop?

```
function SubtractFrom(val, subtractor) {
    return val - subtractor;
}

function PassThrough(val) {
    return val;
}

var num = 10;
var processor = reverse ? SubtractFrom(num-1) : PassThrough;

for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    console.log(processor(i));
}
```

Not knowing Javascript though, I don't know what actual form the function definitions would take.

Answer (score 0):

```
//reverse a number
let c = [2,3,5,67,4]
let sum = '';
let d = c.toString().split('')
console.log(d)
for(let i = d.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sum += d[i]
}
console.log(sum)
```