# Function Returning Square Brackets When Using Array Methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've just started an exercise in Chapter 4 of a book called Eloquent JavaScript. The exercise asks me to do the following:

> "Write a range function that takes two arguments, start and end, and
>   returns an array containing all the numbers from start up to (and
>   including) end."

However, when I write the following code:

```
function range(start, end) {
  array = [];
for (var i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {
  array.push(i);
}
  return array;
}

console.log(range(5, 2));
```

It returns square brackets ( [] ). Does anyone know what the issue might be? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You can't start at 5 and end at 2 if you're _increasing_ the index - makes no sense. It's like trying to walk backwards and forwards at the same time. Try swapping 5 and 2 and see what happens.

Comment: `start` shouldn't be greater than `end`

Comment: Oh, that was dumb of me >_>. And to think that I spent such a long time thinking it was something else. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the range indexes in the wrong order. You cant go from 5 to 2, you need to go from 2 to 5

```
range(2,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning square brackets indicates an empty list. This may or may not be the desired result.

To expand on your question a bit - you could use a range function that is more flexible and able to produce descending lists. See below for example, or in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00ps45k7/2/).

```
function range(start, end) {
    array = [];
    // Determine order
    var delta = (start < end)? 1 : -1;

    for (var i = start; num_compare(i,end,delta); i += delta) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
}

function num_compare(a,b, delta) {
    if(delta == 0) { return false; } // No change? Avoid infinite loop.
    if(delta < 0)  { return a >= b; } // Descending. Continue while a>=b
    if(delta > 0)  { return a <= b; } // Asecending. Continue while a<=b
}

var answer = range(5,2);
console.log(answer);
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer.toString();
```

Now passing in `range(5,2);` will produce the (maybe desired) list of [5,4,3,2].

Related questions/answers of note include:
[reversing order in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586304/how-to-reverse-the-order-in-a-for-loop), [comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591243/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-comparison-operator-a-variable)