# Javascript and/or jquery optimisation and jsPerf

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have an array of objects in a web application, the values of which get updated several times. Im trying to work out the best/fastest way

I have a jsPerf here - http://jsperf.com/marker-assignment-test
The 'normal' test is how Im currently doing it.

Anyone have any ideas for a faster method?

EDIT:
the 'normal' test is how I have it in the web application, but I want to optimise it.
The only thing that can not change, is that the objects are stored in an array, and that several values will need updating at the same time

Comment: Are you currently optimizing real code or do you want to know how you should write it in the first place?

Comment: edited the question (looking to optimise, with one restriction)

Comment: Terrible place to look for optimization.. use the first form only if you are getting paid by lines of code. Look for optimization in your (ab)use of jQuery

Comment: abuse? It doesn't use jquery?

Comment: @DAVIEAC Your web app doesn't use jQuery? Then why did you tag it jQuery ;P What I meant is that this kind of optimization has no effect on the app performance and you should look at actual bottlenecks (Most likely DOM and jQuery related).

Comment: sorry no,  the web app uses jquery, I added it to the jsPerf incase anyone wanted to suggest a more optimal solution using it. My fault I should have been clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are extremely cheap in JavaScript, so you should [look at using them](http://jsperf.com/marker-assignment-test/3). I've cached the result of `myArray[1]` in a variable, and it's quicker than your tests.

If you have many objects in the array, you should also look at optimizing the iteration of the array; [Are loops really faster in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse)

Comment: Fantastic, Iv added it to the main jsPerf. Thanks