# which is faster for-loop or foreach?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, foreach

Let on an array,

Method 1:

```js
var array = ["a","a","a","a","a"];
  for(var i=1; i<=array.length; i++)
      array[i-1] += i;
  console.log(array);
```

Method 2:

```
  var array = ["a","a","a","a","a"];
  var i = 1;
  array.forEach(function(){
      array[i-1] += i;
      i++;
   });
   console.log(array);
```

Both methods on *array* yields same result, that is:

["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"]

But 
1) which is the fastest method? 
2) Is there any other faster way to do the same thing that is convert ["a","a","a","a","a"] to ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"]?
3) Is there a way to know time taken by both code snippet? Please don't be too technical...

Comment: [Here is the answer!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9746791/2014745)

Comment: Why would you use `forEach()` *without* using the arguments it passes to your callback?

Comment: you mean, `arr.forEach(function(**val**){... })` ? **val** not used in code.