# For loop Variations in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In [this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/rethinking-javascript-for-loops/) website there are a list of for loop variations. I can understand the usage of `for(var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len ;i++)` loop (where `arr` is an array), since the `arr.length` isn't calculated in every step there appears to be a marginal performance gain. However what are the advantages of using the other variants? For instance, loops like

1. `for (var i=arr.length; i--;)`
2. `for (var i=0, each; each = arr[i]; i++)`

Are there any noticeable changes in performance when using different for loop variations? I generally use `for(var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len ;i++)` even for very big arrays. So I just want to know if there is something I am missing out here.

Comment: "decrementing" loop are much much faster in js. as for the last one i would not use it , since in js false==0=="" .

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Are loops really faster in reverse...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse)

Comment: @camus The second one can be useful when looping through eg. a collection of DOM elements.

Comment: This [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/loops/32) tests all loops ...

Comment: @ManseUK +1 for JSPerf. It's the first result for googling "jsperf for loops"

Comment: Hi Ashwin. I'm the author of the referenced post. Most of the examples were done for fun and exploration and carry no special benefit aside from demonstrating the flexibility of for loop syntax

Comment: @AngusC, ah i see :) Thank you. Just exploring my options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is widely considered that a reversed while loop

```
var loop = arr.length;
while( loop-- ) {
}
```

is the fastest loop-type available in C-like languages (this also applied to ECMAscript for quite a while, but I think all up-to-date engines are pretty even on standard loops today). ( [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/loop-types-ecmascript) )

Your 'variations' are actually no variations, but just different usage of the `conditional` statement within the `for-loop` (which, actually makes it a variation..doh!). Like

1) `for (var i=arr.length; i--;)`

Just uses the conditional part from the `for-loop` to do both, iterating and checking if `i` has a truthy value. As soon as `i` becomes `0` the loop will end.

2) `for (var i=0, each; each = arr[i]; i++)`

Here we get the element from each iteration, so we can directly access that within the loop body. This is commonly used when you are tired of always repeating `arr[ n ]`.

You're doing well in caching the `.length` property before looping. As you correctly mentioned, it is faster because we don't have to access that property in every iteration. Beyond that, it's also required sometimes in DOM scripting, when dealing with 'live structures' like `HTMLCollections`.

Answer (score 2):

The point is when you're decrementing the iterator, you're actually comparing it to 0 rather than the length, which is faster since the "<, <=, >, >=" operators require type checks on both left and right sides of the operator to determine what comparison behaviour should be used.

the fastest loop is: (If you don't care about the order of course)

```
var i = arr.length
while(i--)
{
}
```

If you do care about the order, the method you're using is fine.

Answer (score 2):

According to [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/loops/32) the fastest type of loop in JavaScript is

```
var arr = new Array(10);
var i = 0;
while (i < arr.length) {
 arr[i];
 i++;
};
```

just ahead of (my default loop)

```
var arr = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
 arr[i];
};
```

With this being the slowest :

```
var arr = new Array(10);
arr.forEach(function(x) {
 x;
});
```

at least on Chrome 17 on OSX 10.7.3. So it seems the "default" loop is fine after all !!!

Comment: These jsperf tests are very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a poor use of a for each loop because it will fail on falsy values , breaking the loop.

```
for (var i=0, each; each = arr[i]; i++)
```

I also wouldn't use this loop ( even tough it may be faster... )

```
for (var i=arr.length; i--;)
```

It looks confusing and is less readable, you might as well write as reverse while loop then.