# Why this loop backwards is much slower than going forward?

Tags: javascript, performance, loops

I have a answer to another guy question here [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string/7924240#7924240)
So I was playing with algorithms [here](http://jsperf.com/count-string-occurrence-in-string/3), and after benchmarking some functions I was wondering why a backwards loop was significantly slower than forward.

[image: graph]

[**Benchmark test here**](http://jsperf.com/charat-forward-vs-charat-backwards)

---

> NOTE: This code below does not work as supposed to be, there are
>   others that work (thats not the point of this question), be aware
>   before Copying>Pasting it

**Forward**

```
function occurrences(string, substring) {

  var n = 0;
  var c = 0;
  var l = substring.length;

  for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i++) {

    if (string.charAt(i) == substring.charAt(c)) {
      c++;
    } else {
      c = 0;
    }

    if (c == l) {
      c = 0;
      n++;
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

**Backwards**

```
function occurrences(string, substring) {

  var n = 0;
  var l = substring.length - 1;
  var c = l;

  for (i = string.length; i > 1; i--) {

    if (string.charAt(i) == substring.charAt(c)) {
      c--;
    } else {
      c = l;
    }

    if (c < 0) {
      c = l;
      n++;
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the bottle-neck myself.

when I did this

```
for (i = string.length; i > 1; i--) {
```

I accidentaly deleted the "var" from `var i`, so I've made `i` global.
After fixing it I got the expected results.

```
for (var i = string.length; i > 1; i--) {
```

I never though that this may be a HUGE difference, so pay attention guys.

[Fixed Benckmark test here](http://jsperf.com/charat-forward-vs-charat-backwards/4)

## Before:

[image: Before]

## After:

[image: After]

PS: for practical use, do NOT use this functions, the [indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string/7924240#7924240) version is much faster.

Answer (score 4):

I think the backwards test has a bug:

`for (i = string.length; i > 1; i--) {`

should be

`for (i = string.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`

When `i` is `string.length`, `string.charAt(i)` is undefined. Do this several thousand times, and it could yield a substantial difference.

[Here's a modified test](http://jsperf.com/charat-forward-vs-charat-backwards/2) that seems to yield much closer to identical performances.

Comment: you are correct about the `i>=0` but not about the undefined, because I was just not going till the beginnig of the string and not checking the character at position 0. Thanks but this is not the cause of the bottleneck.

Comment: I found the issue, so I answered myself.

Answer (score 0):

What data are you testing with. If your data has lots of matching prefixes but not many false matches the other way round , that might affect it.

also wont that search bug on cases like  "aaabbaaa" try to find "aab" it will match aa, then fail , then continue from third a and fail. ?

Comment: both functions are using the same input, but your example doesn't make sense to me. You will always get only one match on `aaabbaaa` to `aab` no matter what.

Comment: yes you should but it seems to me that the first code will not find a match for aab in aaabbaaa.

Comment: it will go: Aaabbaaa AAabbaaa AAAbbaaa (FAIL) then continue matching aaaBbaaa to Aab (FAIL) and will not match.

Comment: i would study regular expression matchers and finite state machines. ;) Generating a simple DFA is often the fastest way to match stuff, especially if you can compile it straight to bytecode which gets jitted.

Comment: that new one will probably work, but i am not sure if it is faster than a proper DFA or NFA for cases where you have long false matches.

Comment: I'm sure it is slower than Regex solution, would be a lot faster in C, but due to Javascript nature native functions will always be faster. the bottleneck is probably the string comparison `==`but thats not the point of the question, it was just for studying purposes not for real application. Thank you anyway ;D

Answer (score 0):

Because they are not complete mirrored functions, add `console.log()`s inside all `if`s and `else`s of both functions and compare the results, you will see that the tests aren't fair.

You did something wrong. I suggest to ensure that they both work as expected before even start the testings.

Comment: no, they are equivalent, is the same logic and I have the same output from both.