# How to turn jQuery each() into regular javascript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, jquery

A couple questions:

1. Is a regular javascript loop (to loop through a series of elements) faster/more efficient than using jQuery `each()` ??
2. If so, what is the best way to write the following code as a regular javascript loop?

`$('div').each(function(){ //... })`

Comment: If you're really interested in loop efficiency, have a look here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse

Comment: A `for` loop is faster, but note that if what you're doing within the loop involves callback functions that need to use the loop index variable later then you would need to introduce a closure and that would (more or less) cancel out the efficiency gains.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, removing the `each()` will give you slightly better performance. This is how you could write a for loop for a list of elements.

```
var divs = $('div');

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    var thisDiv = divs[i]; // element

    var $thisDiv = $(divs[i]); // jquery object

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: To answer the first part of the question, yes a regular loop is going to be slightly more efficient due to the removal of some overhead.  The difference should be very small.

Comment: Is `divs[i]` a jquery object? when i do `thisDiv.find('a')`, for example, I get an error...

Comment: `divs[i]` is not a jquery object. You would have to `$(divs[i])`

Comment: it's faster to declare `divs.length` outside of the loop

Answer (score 5):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    l = divs.length, i, cur;

for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
    cur = divs[i];
    // do stuff with cur here
}
```

Please continue on your path to removing jQuery in the name of efficiency. This code is approximately fifty times faster than the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: It's only 50x faster if you have nothing in the "do stuff with cur here" part.  It's faster, but the 50x is misleading in the grand scheme.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, due to the first already being answered;

I was also interested in this, and I decided to benchmark the two to find the difference using Gabe's example. The answer is, in circumstances of wanting a jQuery object as the final result:

They perform exactly the same.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-native-selectors

Firefox actually finds the jQuery version faster, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jquery `.each()`

```
$('div').each(function(){ //... })
```

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()`, then convert the HTMLCollection into a JavaScript array. Then you can map over the array of elements.

```
 const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.my-elements')
 const $elems = [].slice.call(elems)
 $elems.map( (elem) => { console.log(elem) })
```