# How to get element id as function parameter

Tags: javascript

I am studying as front end developer. I am new to javascript. And i got this problem when i execute a js from backend passing some elements id. It displays some error **Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**.
My js:

```
function disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls(elementsContainerId) {
   console.error("Elements id from backend: " + elementsContainerId);
   var container = document.getElementById(elementsContainerId);
   // I am checking here length of elements
   console.error("Elements length : " + container.length);
   // It displays Elements length : undefined
     container.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
      if (!$(this).hasScrollBar()) return;
     // If container div has a scrollbar it will do nothing

        var event = e.originalEvent,
        d = event.wheelDelta || -event.detail;

        this.scrollTop += (d < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30;
        e.preventDefault();  
    }, {passive: false});
}
```

Any solution of this ?

And my backend passing elements id

```
    if (!isMobile)
        JSUtil.execFn("disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls", checkboxGrp.getElementsContainerId());
```

Comment: It means that you have passed an `id`, that no element in your html contains.

Comment: Show us how you are calling this method. Create a working snippet using `<>`.

Comment: @VigneshRaja Exactly. Use console.log to log elementsContainerId.

Comment: then how can i get elements ? Please help me i am a newbie

Comment: @KhShuren-Erdene, add this line console.log(elementsContainerId); below  "function disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls(elementsContainerId) {"

Comment: when i type and execute `console.log(elementsContainerId);`. Its displays `undefined`.

Comment: I have multiple containers. So i need some loop ?

Comment: Where are you getting the IDs from? Show the code that calls this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys i solved my problem :). But i don't understand well how this working. My solution is:

```
function disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls(elementsContainerId) {
  console.error('containerId: ' + elementsContainerId);
  // First is element undefined or Not rendered to DOM my opinion
  (function() {
    if (typeof elementsContainerId === "undefined") {
        throw new Error("elementsContainerId parameter is undefined");
    }
    var container = document.getElementById(elementsContainerId);
    console.error("Elements ID : " + container.length);
    container.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
        if (!$(this).hasScrollBar()) return;
        // logger.debug('has scroll');

        var event = e.originalEvent,
            d = event.wheelDelta || -event.detail;

        this.scrollTop += (d < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30;
        e.preventDefault();
     }, { passive: false });

  })();

}
```

And i thought maybe js worked before html elements not loaded thats i got `null and undefined` error. By the way thanks for all comments and answers :).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to pass an function parameter while calling.

disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls('yourIDElement');

Comment: i have multiple elements

Comment: In this case you should use classes instead of unique id's. Also take a look at each functions if you are using jquery otherwise, this is going to help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117018/how-to-turn-jquery-each-into-regular-javascript-loop

Comment: Hold on i will try it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your `elementsContainerId` parameter isn't `undefined` or `null`. In some place, you are calling the `disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls` without a parameter, with an undefined variable, with a variable which value is `null`.

You could check that `elementsContainerId` is not `undefined` or `null` just before your logic and throw an error if condition is true. In this way, you will instantly notice if your are passing a wrong parameter to your function.

```
function disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls(elementsContainerId) {
   if(typeof elementsContainerId === "undefined" || elementsContainerId === null) {
       throw new Error("elementsContainerId parameter is undefined or null");
   }
   // ...
}
```

Also, after the first validation, you could check if the element with the specified id exists (just to be shure that the `mousewheel` event is bound)

Comment: i tried this. and i got `elementsContainerId parameter is undefined` this error message. So this means i passing wrong values or something gone wrong ?

Comment: Yes, wrong parameter value. You should check the calling method and, maybe, put a `console.log` of your parameter right before the call to `disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls`.

Comment: And i print my variable container `console.error("Elements Id: " + container)`. It gives me `VM39881:1237 Elements ID : [object HTMLDivElement]`

Comment: @KhShuren-Erdene please show the code that call `disableOtherCheckBoxGrpScrolls` function so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry @KhShuren-Erdene but you should post the code of any uknown function like `JSUtil.execFn` and `getElementsContainerId`.

Comment: thanks for answer. And sorry for running your time :)