# Why is i-- faster than i++ in loops?

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript - Are loops really faster in reverse…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse)

I don't know if this question is valid in other languages or not, but I'm asking this specifically for `JavaScript`.

I see in some articles and questions that the fastest loop in JavaScript is something like:

```
for(var i = array.length; i--; )
```

Also in Sublime Text 2, when you try to write a loop, it suggests:

```
for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Things[i]
};
```

I want to know, why is `i--` faster than `i++` in loops?