# How do I iterate an array-like-object by order (not index)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JSON data:

```
{  
  "113":{"id":"113","title":"Coal","hex":"4f4f4f"},
  "116":{"id":"116","title":"White","hex":"fdfbf7"},
  "115":{"id":"115","title":"Greylead","hex":"b3b3b3"}
}
```

Which is in the markup on a data attribute I can access like so:

```
var arr = $("#element).data('arr');
```

And then do stuff with each item. Like so:

```
$.each( arr, function( index, obj ){ 
   console.log( obj.title + ' is #' + obj.hex );
}
```

But the order of the items in the data isn't being preserved.

`$.each` seems to iterate through by the leading number of each item in the data, NOT the order that items are actually in the array. I get my output in the numerical order 113, 115, 116 instead of 113, 116, 115 (which is the actual order of the items in the data).

How would I iterate through the items in the *actual* order?

Comment: "How would I iterate through the items in the actual order?" - there's no actual order. JS object keys are conceptually unordered.

Comment: What's "actual order" in an un-ordered data structure?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté — "Conceptually unordered". So this is just a fundamental difference between JS and something like PHP?

Comment: @Dominic I said "conceptually" as there's no specification regarding object keys ordering, though browsers tend to follow some enumeration rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If order matters to you, use plain array:

```
[
    {"key": "113", "id":"113","title":"Coal","hex":"4f4f4f"}, 
    {"key": "116", "id":"116","title":"White","hex":"fdfbf7"}, 
    {"key": "115", "id":"115","title":"Greylead","hex":"b3b3b3"}
]
```

Then plain loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    console.log( obj.title + ' is #' + obj.hex );
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/V4XcE/).

If you want to search for item based on its key, you now have to loop over all items to find it. For better efficiency you can create additional "mapper" object:

```
var mapper = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    mapper[obj.key] = obj;
}
```

Then to look for item based on key:

```
key = "115";
if (mapper[key]) {
    //exists...
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4XcE/1/).

Comment: @roasted true, but for plain arrays I prefer to use the plain loop, no need for a key.

Comment: plain `for` loops are some millersecondz faster (as it doesn't apply a callback creating a new execution context/function scope for each element in the array).

Comment: Well yes, my latest benchmarks show that V8 can optimize native `for` loops to be even faster than the usual `var i = arr.length; while(i--) {}` (contrary to [popular believe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1340634/1331430) which was true until not long ago), but this is just implementation trivia. `=]`

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks! I am using the structure `"id" : { "stuff": "etc..." }` on the assumption that it would be faster (and more convenient) to get an item's details by the id; e.g., arr[113].title == 'Coal'. In your answer, is there a performance issue if I have to search all the data for an item with id of 113 instead?

Comment: @Dominic fair point. It depends on the size of the array. In my opinion if 100 or less it's really too minor to make any difference. Otherwise, build another object which is associative array mapping each item of the plain array based on its key. If relevant let me know and I'll come with sample code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've done the latter (I made a sort order associative array) because it means no changes to the rest of my code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That said, what would you recommend as a fast way of looking up item details by id (based on the plain array format in your answer)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Smart! I wouldn't have thought of doing it quite like that and it's perfect for my use case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

just go this site  http://json.parser.online.fr and paste this

```
   {  
    "113":{"id":"113","title":"Coal","hex":"4f4f4f"},
    "116":{"id":"116","title":"White","hex":"fdfbf7"},
    "115":{"id":"115","title":"Greylead","hex":"b3b3b3"}
   }
```

I think u will get your answer where JSON.parse maintains ORDER and eval('('+data+')') maintains INDEX.Then run a plain loop and do your other jobs.