# Variable in for loop is a string

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm not sure if this is normal behavior, but running this:

```
for (var i in [1, 2, 3]) {
    console.log(i + 1);
}
```

Results in this:

```
// 01
// 11
// 21
```

Could somebody please explain, why is `var i` being treated like a string in this situation and not if I do `for (var i = 0; i < [1, 2, 3].length; i++)`?

Comment: If you are using a platform that supports [a suitable subset of ES6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-for..of_loops), a for-of loop will give you the behavior you want: `for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) { console.log(i + 1); }`

Comment: for (var i of [1, 2, 3]) { console.log(typeof i); console.log(typeof (i + 1));  }


for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) {  console.log(typeof i);  console.log(typeof (i + 1));  }

Both are resulting in number type.
But remember in js everything treated as object and key objects are usually strings.

Comment: Just when you think you've seen all the weird JavaScript behaviours, something like this comes up.

Comment: [Why is using a `for ... in` loop for JavaScript arrays a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: [Is JavaScript array index a string or an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27537677/1048572)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Its most likely because in this for loop style (for..in), it is treating `i` as a key, and since keys in objects are usually strings (yes, an array is a type of object in javascript), it is treating it as a String.

`parseInt(i)` works in this situation, but for good programming practice, you would want to use a `for` loop that looks similar to this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // do work with each array element here
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if the code you've submitted is not just a boiled down example to illustrate a bigger issue, use the old fashioned `for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){}`

Comment: While the end result is what the OP wanted, I would call this a bad programming practice.

Comment: You absolutely should not use `parseInt` here. Rather use a proper loop.

Comment: I addressed the question, and the solution fits. I could provide a proper loop if you guys would like.

Comment: @You: Thanks, much better, though looping backwards is quite unidiomatic

Comment: @Bergi you know what, I think I might make a new question for that, it has to do with the editor I use....actually, I just found my answer as to *why* this type of loop is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17484696/2020002

Comment: @You It's not "better". You should favour readability over microoptimisations.

Answer (score 18):

The reason is that `for .. in` iterates object properties ("keys"), even for arrays. The "keys" in this case are the "indexes" of the array but it's still just object keys. As all object keys are strings, `i` gets a string value.

Answer (score 12):

I think you want the values of the array, not the keys. If you can't use ES6, [Xorifelse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38985512/1034669) works, but if you can, there is `for ... of` that works exactly as you probably thought:

```js
for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) {
  console.log(i + 1);
}
```

There is also `Array.prototype.forEach` in ES5 and up:

```js
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(value, index) {
  console.log(value + 1);
});
```

Comment: here you get the value, in the OP's code, they get the key.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote.

Answer (score 10):

Using the `in` keyword you're looping over each *key* in the object and those are *string* types and when using the `+` operator on a *string* will cause it to do a **concatenation** assignment.

If you want to perform an **arithmetic** assignment both the *left* and the *right* value of the operator have to be an *integer* type. A solution would be to try to parse the string to an integer:

```
console.log(parseInt("0") + 1); // 1
```

**However...**
 You should be looping over the *value* instead:

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3];

for(var key in data){
  console.log('a: data['+ key + '] = ' + data[key]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log('b: data['+ i + '] = ' + data[i]);
}

data.forEach(function(value, index){
  console.log('c: data[' + index + '] = ' + value);
});
```

---

You could use the [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#IteratorForOfOperator) method to loop over the value alone:

```js
for(let v of [1, 2, 3]) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

The drawback of this method is [the incompatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) of older android devices since its a somewhat new standard.

---

If you're using jQuery, you can also take a look at [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) as it allows for a key, value iteration in a nice one-liner that is compatible with older devices.

```js
$.each([1, 2, 3], function(index, value) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because `i` is a key/ index of every element, and it's string type.
So you are in fact concatenating string and int – the result is string.

Answer (score 4):

That is because with the "in" keyword you traverse the keys of the object, not array indexes. However in this case, since the object is an array, the keys of the items in are indexes. And last, the keys in a for..in loop are strings.

So if you need numeric indexes of an array, you need to use a regular for loop.

```
var array = [0, 1, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well when you use the `for...in` loop you're visiting each key from an object. Arrays are objects and their keys are numbers, but usually object keys are treated like strings.

If you want to convert the key to int, you can use `parseInt` function. 
[link!](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/)

Answer (score -5):

```js
for (var i in [1, 2, 3]) {
    console.log(parseInt(i) + parseInt(1));
}
```

Comment: No need to parse an existing integer type.. only `i` is a string.