# Waypoints with non-jQuery/framework build

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I've used waypoints.js a few times before to great success. Using code like the example below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.section').waypoint(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('in-view');
    },
    {offset: '65%'});
});
```

That was created using version `jQuery Waypoints - v2.0.3`. I'm trying to use the same code on a website I've inherited which uses `Waypoints 4.0.1` but the above code doesn't work and I think that's because the script is the non-jQuery version.

So my question is, how would I format/write the above code in a noframework build?

I struggle enough with jQuery so code the the example below is totally foreign to me!

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
  }
})
```

How would I write my jQuery script in *what I guess* is plain javascript? Can someone shed some light on this please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent would be something like the following:

```
var waypoints = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
for (var i = waypoints.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: waypoints[i],
        handler: function(direction) {
            this.element.classList.toggle('in-view');
        },
        offset: '65%',
    });
}
```

The Waypoint documentation is quite descriptive here: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

**Update:**
[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/javrjR)

Comment: None of that makes sense to me (at the minute) haha! For example the `querySelectorAll`, I don't know where I'd have got that from! I suppose when you're not used to Javascript this probably isn't the easiest place to start. Thanks a lot for the reply. I'll give it a shot and let you know how I get on!

Comment: Actually, in this case you could also use `.getElementsByClassName()` –which might be more self-explanatory– instead of `.querySelectorAll()`. Both of these calls return an array-like object, containing the selected tags.

Comment: Ah ok, what about the `.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) ` bit? The rest from there _kinda_ makes sense. `element` being where you declare the variable you've defined earlier (waypoints[i]) followed by the function you want applied to it?

Comment: Regarding the for loop: it is just a way of writing it. You will find more about that on the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484227/javascript-improved-native-for-loop  As for the `this.element`: this is how `Waypoint` implented the `handler` callback. The `this` keyword is a reference to the Waypoint instance, which keeps a reference to the DOM element with its `element` property. So yes, `this.element` equals to `waypoints[i]`.

Comment: I couldn't get the code to work with my script so I think it might be best if I create a codepen later on and update my post.

Comment: I just have updated the answer, as I noticed that a comma was missing from the end of the handler callback definition. A codepen is on the way.

Comment: That's ace, looks like it works a treat! I'll give it a good test tomorrow. Thanks again!