# Any reason to traverse arrays from end to start in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following seems like a very common practice in **Javascript** :

```
for (var i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { /* do stuff here */ };
```

I never noticed this in other languages though ... Does it have any benefits over:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { /* do stuff here */ };
```

The only thing that comes to mind is the caching of the array length in the first one, which wouldn't be such a huge performance I'd guess. You could also have :

```
var top =  array.Length;
for (var i = 0; i < top; i++) { /* do stuff here */ };
```

Giving you the same `benefit` of caching, but might be a bit less `performant` if you are minimizing your code (shaving maybe 8 characters when minifying the script)

Comment: Depends entirely on what "stuff" is.

Comment: Another reason: allows you to remove items from the array as you traverse it.

Comment: What code is in the place that says `/* do stuff here */`?

Comment: You need to refer to this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, it makes a huge difference.

```
var nodes = element.children, l = nodes.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) element.removeChild(nodes[i]);
// ^ FAILS WITH ERROR (unless l is 0 or 1)

for( i=l-1; i>=0; i--) element.removeChild(nodes[i]);
// ^ works
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, going backwards makes things easier when you are removing elements from an array, but it also does provide a slight performance boost as seen in [this example (jsperf)](http://jsperf.com/loopdir). I suspect that starting at the end and working your way to the beginning is faster because you don't have to grab the length property of the array after every iteration of the loop.