# javascript array traversal - efficiency

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

So, I have seen this piece of code at alot of places:

```
for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {

}
```

I am aware that is the length caching of the array.

Today I saw this:

> `var len = myArray.length;
>   var i = 0;
>   while(i++ < len)`

Efficiency wise, both would be the same, right? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Decrementing is faster. Var i = myArray.length-1; while(i--){ //code here }. Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse

Comment: http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-length

Comment: Firefox 28. Normal for loop is fastest:
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
[jsperf](http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-length/5)

Comment: The bottom line is: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" – Donald Knuth, 1974. You really shouldn't have to care about whether it's faster to increment or decrement – leave that up to compiler optimizations and focus on the actual logic instead.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a jsperf test case here:

http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-length

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //nothing
}

var arrlength = arr.length;

for (i = 0; i < arrlength; i++) {
    //nothing
}

var arrlength = arr.length,
    i = 0;

while (arrlength > i++) {
    //nothing
}

var arrlength = arr.length;

while (arrlength--) {
    //nothing
}
```

If the test cases can be improved upon, please let me know in the comments. With a small number of tests, it seems IE11 is better optimized for the `while` cases, while Chrome 31 appears to prefer the second `for` loop (which is fairly similar to the `while` cases).

Comment: Exactly, thats what I was about to bring up, different browsers are showing different performances based on the loops, I guess its about making the right pick.

Comment: In your forwards while loop, you iterate from `1` to `arr.length` (included), instead of from `0` to `arr.length-1` (included).

Comment: @Oriol - While I don't think it will make an appreciable difference, I've modified that test.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Still the same problem. The performance should be the same, but if you iterate `[1,2,3]` like this, you get `2`,`3`,`undefined` instead of `1`,`2`,`3`. I would use `i = -1; while (++i < length) { }` instead.

Comment: @Oriol - The purpose is for it to run a certain number of times. The utility of it inside the loop is beside the point. You are suggesting a micro-optimization.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No, I'm not optimizing it, I'm just pointing your code requires using `arr[i-1]` instead of `arr[i]`, so if someone uses your code to iterate arrays, he must be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "normal" loop, you can also change `i < len` to `i !== len`. This makes the loop a lot faster, because the the check for inequality is very fast. The caching of the variable is not so important, but it do no harm.

So a fast loop in javascript can written as follows:

```
for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i !== len; i++) {

}
```

**UPDATE**

I made some performance tests a while ago and this was what I found out. But nowadays the browsers don't show the same behaviour, furthermore it's the opposite (`<` is faster than `!==`) . Here is a test I made just now: http://jsperf.com/loop-inequality-check

So forget about the posting above ;)