# Javascript add same element N times in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Suppose I have map like this:

```
var map = {"a" : 100, "b" : 200, "c": 700};
```

And I want an Array consisting of "a" 100 times, "b" 200 times and "c" 700 times:

```
map_array = [a, a, a, a, ... a, b, b, b, ... b, c, c, c, ... c]
```

Simple solution is to just loop the frequency times and push in the array:

```
var map_array = []
for(key in map)
{
    for(var i=1; i <= map[key] ; i++)
    {
       map_array.push(key)
    }
}
```

But this will obviously take time to processes with large data, can we rework the above function to make it more efficient?

Comment: And what you will do with a saved millisecond?

Comment: Its is taking approximately 2 to 3 seconds working with actual data, I guess we can reduce this time :)

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array) for other ways

Comment: @Teemu (O)N^2 = terrible performance.

Comment: @Gaurav Are you sure it's JS taking the time, not any rendering? Try with a direct assignment, a function call always takes some extra.

Comment: @Teemu yes time mentioned is only for JS, and tried direct assignment too..

Comment: @Gaurav: Why do you want such an array?

Comment: @PhilH want to add these markers on a map.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the real problem here is constructing the sub-arrays of repeated `"a"`'s, `"b"`'s, and `"c"`'s. Once you have them, you can just `concat` them to make your final array. 
So, what we really want is a function `f(x, n)` which creates an array filled with `n` `x`'s.

So, as a standard testbed, I'm going to define a pair of `clock` functions. The first measures the time it takes some array-filling function to create 500000 arrays, each containing 2187 `"a"`'s. The second measures the time it takes some array-filling function to create 500 arrays, each containing 1594323 `"a"`'s. I chose powers of three because some of my algorithms are binary-based, and I wanted to avoid any coincidences. Regardless, all of the algorithms will for for any `n`.

```
var clock1=function(f)
{
    var m,t;
    m=500000;
    t=Date.now();
    while(m--)
    {
        f("a", 2187);
    }
    t=Date.now()-t;
    return t;
};

var clock2=function(f)
{
    var m,t;
    m=500;
    t=Date.now();
    while(m--)
    {
        f("a", 1594323);
    }
    t=Date.now()-t;
    return t;
};
```

I'm running this test on my local machine running plain v8 in strict mode. Below are some candidates for `f`:

---

### Linear Method

As already suggested by Alex, you can do this using a linear loop. Simply define an array and run a loop which executes `n` times, each time adding one `x` to our array.

```
var f=function(x,n)
{
    var y;
    y=Array(n);
    while(n--)
    {
        y[n]=x;
    }
    return y;
};
```

We can optimize by using a counting variable, `n` to avoid calling `push` or `y.length`, as well as pre-initializing the array to the desired length. (Both suggested by Alex.) My backwards `while` loop is just an old habit that may [boost performance slightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse).

This function takes 2200ms to pass `clock1`, and 90658ms to pass `clock2`.

### Partial Binary Method

We can also try constructing it using binary concatenation. The idea is that you start out with a single-element array, then , if its length is significantly less than the target length, you `concat` it with itself, effectively doubling it. When you get it close to the target size, switch back to adding elements one at a time until it reaches its target size:

```
var f=function(x,n)
{
    var y,m;
    y=[x];
    m=1;
    while(m<n)
    {
        if(m*2<=n)
        {
            y=y.concat(y);
            m*=2;
        }
        else
        {
            y[m]=x;
            m++;
        }
    }
    return y;
};
```

Here, `m` is just a counting variable to keep track of the size of y.

This function takes 3630ms to pass `clock1`, and 42591ms to pass `clock2`, making it 65% *slower* than the linear method for small arrays, but 112% faster for large ones.

### Full Binary Method

We can boost performance still further, however, by using full binary construction. The partial binary method suffers because it is forced to switch to element-by-element addition when it approaches its target length (on average, about 75% of the way through). We can fix this:

First, convert the target size into binary and save it to an array.  Now, define `y` to be a single-element array `z` to be an empty array. Then, loop (backwards) through the binary array, for each element `concat`ing `y` with itself. In each iteration, if the respective binary digit is 1, save `y` into `z`. Finally, `concat` all of the elements of `z` together. The result is your complete array.

So, in order to fill an array of length 700, it first converts 700 to binary:

```
[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]
```

Looping backwards across it, it performs 9 `concat`'s and 6 element-additions, generating a `z` which looks like this:

```
[0,0,4,8,16,32,128,512]
// I've written the lengths of the sub-arrays rather than the arrays themselves.
```

When it `concat`'s everything in `z` together, it gets a single array of length 700, our result.

```
var f=function(x,n)
{
    var y,z,c;
    c=0;
    y=[x];
    z=[];
    while(n>0)
    {
        if(n%2)
        {
            z[c++]=y;
            n--;
        }
        if(n===0)
        {
            break;
        }
        n/=2;
        y=y.concat(y);
    }
    return z.concat.apply([],z);
};
```

To optimize, I've compressed the binary conversion step and the loop together here. `z.concat.apply([],z)` uses a bit of `apply` magic to flatten `z`, an array of arrays, into a single array. For some reason, this is faster than concating to `z` on the fly. The second `if` statement prevents it from doubling `y` one last time after the computation is complete.

This function takes 3157ms to pass `clock1` and 26809ms to pass `clock2`, making it 15% faster than the partial binary method for small arrays and 59% faster for large ones. It is still 44% slower than the linear method for small arrays.

### Binary String Method

The `concat` function is weird. The larger the arrays to be concatenated, the more efficient it becomes, relatively speaking. In other words, combining two arrays of length 100 is significantly faster than combining four arrays of length 50 using `concat`. As a result, as the involved arrays get larger, `concat` becomes more efficient than `push`, or direct assignment. This is one of the main reasons why the binary methods are faster than the linear method for large arrays. Unfortunately, `concat` also suffers because it copies the involved arrays each time. Because arrays are objects, this gets quite costly. Strings are less complex than arrays, so perhaps using them would avoid this drain? We can simply use string addition (analogous to concatenation) to construct our array, and the `split` the resulting string.

A full binary method based on strings would look like this:

```
var f=function(x,n)
{
    var y,z;
    y=""+x;
    z="";
    while(n>0)
    {
        if(n%2)
        {
            z+=y;
            n--;
        }
        if(n===0)
        {
            break;
        }
        y+=y;
        n/=2;
    }
    return z.split("");
};
```

This function takes 3484ms to pass `clock1` and 14534ms to pass `clock2`, making it 10% slower than the array-based full binary method at computing small arrays, but 85% faster for large arrays.

---

So, overall, its a mixed bag. The linear method gets very good performance on smaller arrays and is extremely simple. The binary string method, however, is a whopping 524% faster on large arrays, and is actually slightly less complex than the binary array method.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature in ECMA6 called `.repeat()`

It will solve your issue as magic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const map = {"a" : 10, "b" : 20, "c": 7};
const keys = Object.keys(map);
let finalArr = [];

keys.forEach(key=>{
  finalArr = [...finalArr,...((key+" ").repeat(map[key]).trim().split(" "))];
})

console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I don't recommend this solution, but check the comments on this answer in order to get most performant answer.

```
    var arrays = Object.keys(map).map(function(obj) {
      var i = 0, l = map[obj], s = "";
      for(;i<l;++i) {
        s+= obj +",";
      }
      return s.split(",");
    });
```

It actually returns three arrays with values, but you can flatten them later with:

```
map_array = map_array.concat.apply(map_array, arrays);
```

http://jsperf.com/map-vs-forin

Comment: Your 'forin' test is biased because you fetch the key within map at every step of the loop. With this simple optimization forin wins: http://jsperf.com/map-vs-forin/4

Comment: Good comments. And apparently @Alex's reply is currently the fastest. Nice that we went this discussion through :).

Comment: yap, pretty interesting!

Comment: I've seen that the forin test also initializes the Array with the wrong length, thus the array is resized many times. Using the forin2 test here, the array is allocated once, which makes the function much faster: http://jsperf.com/map-vs-forin/5 Also the forin3 is a slight optimization of forin2 which performs better in some browsers (e.g. Chrome runs forin3 better and FF runs forin2 better on my PC).

Comment: Surprisingly, this seems javascript engine dependent phenomenon, tried @vdavid case in firefox 28.0 and found above results quite different, check http://jsperf.com/js-array-bulk-insertion in both Chrome & Firefox

Comment: In your 'For in push' case, you add elements to an array that has already been allocated, resulting in twice the memory used (and the first half having undefined values). Apart from that, yes I have different results with Chrome and FF. In the other test (forin-vs-map) with Internet Explorer I even had better results for the first forin (which is the worst results in all other browsers I've tested). So yes the JS engine really makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe defining the array length may be more performant, at least your garbage collector will be happier:

```
map_array = new Array(map.length);
var c = 0;
for (key in map) {
  var max = map[key];
  for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    map_array[c] = key;
    c++;
  }
}
```

thats more performant than using **map()**

http://jsperf.com/map-vs-forin/3