# Calling functions within Angular for multiple JSON objects

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to get an Angular controller to consume some JSON, as below and make a call to the "userService" which has a function called "calculateAge".  This function will do a diff between the date provided, and the individual JSON objects dateOfBirth to return an age.

I know this might not be the best way of achieving this, this is just an illustrative example.

What I am having difficulties with is calling the userService.calculateAge and getting it to populate an "age" value on each JSON object.  I ideally want the value the function returns each time to do this, so that I can better understand how functions can be called within Angular.

My gut instinct is that I am nearly there, and perhaps need to use a for-each loop or similar, however my Angular skills consist of about 2 days learning!

Sample data:

```
[{
   "firstName":"Bob", "lastName":"Smith", "dateOfBirth":"14-12-1988",
   "email":"BSmith", "mobileNumber":null, "landLineNumber":null,
   "isAdmin":false, "isModerator":false, "isEnabled":false, "isActivated":false
 }, {
   "firstName":"Jo", "lastName":"Smith", "dateOfBirth":"15-03-1990",
   "email":"Smithy", "mobileNumber":null, "landLineNumber":null,
   "isAdmin":false, "isModerator":false, "isEnabled":false, "isActivated":false
}]
```

My AngularJS controller and service

```
angular.module("UserApp", [])
.service('userService', function () {
    return {
        calculateAge: function (dateOfBirth) {

            return "23"; //dummy age value here
        }
    };
})
.controller("listUsersController", ['$scope', '$http', 'userService', function ($scope, $http, userService) {
    $http.get("/user/")

        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.users = data;

            var age = userService.calculateAge($scope.users.dateOfBirth);
            $scope.users.age = age;


        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
        });
}] ...
```

Comment: Could you post the response from your API? IE, what's in data?

Do you maybe mean to set $scope.users[x].age instead of $scope.users.age?

Comment: I would normally post it through my API, however I was trying to find an example scenario - for something slightly different. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything specifically to do with `Angular`.

You want to do a loop after you get your data back to send each `user` to your service. That way you can add the new properties as you loop through them the first time.

```
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.users = data;

        for (var i = $scope.users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            $scope.users[i].age = userService.calculateAge($scope.users[i].dateOfBirth);
        };

    })
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  Your right, in that it isn't really Angular specific, and perhaps is better as a JS question. :)

Comment: Interesting loop method.

Comment: @emzy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340589/javascript-are-loops-really-faster-in-reverse. Minimal, but something. It's also Sublime's default `improved native loop` when I am typing code quickly, so it usually wins.